# Upgraded to ubuntu 9.04 django test are now slow

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, testing, ubuntu-9.04

Upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 9.04 and runing latest trunk of django and my test suite has tripled in time to run.

```
Python2.6
Mysql
Django 1.1 beta 1 SVN-10137
```

Comment: Anything else slow? Or just the tests?

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the Official Jaunty IRC (#ubuntu+1 on Freenode)

> Jaunty is NOT RELEASED and NOT SUPPORTED. It will most certainly break your system.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that your tests are running in a transaction. Is MySQL using the InnoDB or MyISAM backend? If you were using InnoDB before and now MyISAM there is no transaction support in MyISAM.